# Bind manager credential on ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider Spring framework

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, ldap, jhipster

On a JHipster application, I've added a custom authentication provider, to verify user and password of Active Directory users that have login inside. This custom component implements AuthenticationProvider, and inside "authenticate" method, istance an ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider object to get authentication and verify presense on specifical groups.

With a simple A.D. test environment I've no problem, but in production, my company ask me to bind a service account, and I cannot found any method to setup manager-ad and password. How can I get around this problem?

On Spring documentation I've read the phrase "There is no concept of a "manager" user."

My app use 5.1.8.RELEASE
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java), it validates the user's credentials by binding using the user's credentials. That's really the only way to validate credentials.

I assume, since it has already made a successful bind, it just continues on making whatever search it needs to.

There might be a way to use different credentials for reading the groups, but it all depends on what your current code looks like. But there really is little point in doing this. You *have to* bind using the user's credentials to validate their credentials. So you may as well continue using that same connection.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel. NOw I've changed the user bind with the service account, and added `(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName="+authentication.getName()+"))` on search string, to looking for the real user that ask for authentication. As result, I've all the information about the user, but how can I check the password of this?

Comment: You can't. :) Like I said, the only way to validate credentials is to bind with the user's credentials.